# play framework 2 with scala: pretify json

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using the play framework 2 native support for json (http://www.playframework.org/documentation/latest/ScalaJson) and I have a JsValue that I'm converting to string to save it to a text file, like this

```
val json: JsValue = [....]
Json.stringify(json)
```

Which works fine, but generates something like this:

```
{"tokens":[{"id":"1000","token":"DON...
```

I was wondering if there's an easy way to generate a formatted json like this

```
{
  "tokens":
    [
      {
        "id":"1000",
        "token":"DON...
```

Comment: Easier solution : install a Json prettify extension directly on your browser (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-prettifier/kccpfgilgmgbipamhohknpokhibinhhj)

Comment: I already have one, I'm programatically generating a json file, not viewing it from the browser

Answer (score 1):

I used liftweb JSON package with its [`Printer`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.json.Printer%24) object/trait. Works 'pretty' well:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs._, concurrent._, json._

import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports.{MongoConnection, MongoCursor, WriteConcern}
import com.mongodb.casbah.query.Imports._
import com.novus.salat.json._

import net.liftweb.json.{render => jsonRender, _}    

class Application extends Controller {

def getJson(id: String) = Action { implicit request =>
  val objPromise = Akka.future(Database.getById(id))
  Async {
    objPromise.orTimeout("Error", 1000).map { o =>
      o.fold(
         hit => Ok(hit.map{ o: DBObject => pretty(jsonRender(ToJValue(o)))}.getOrElse("")).as("text/json"),
         timeout => InternalServerError(timeout)
      )
    }
  }
}
```